# retrning an associative array from mysqli statement result

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code.

```
public function fetch_questions($count=null)
{
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT question,question_title FROM questions order by id");
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($question,$question_title);

    $arr = array();
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $arr = array('question_title'=>$question_title,'question'=>$question);
    }
    $stmt->close();

    return $arr;
}
```

The output only contents one row, the last row. how can retrieve all records?

```
$questions = $db->fetch_questions();
var_dump($questions);
```

Output of var_dump:

```
    array
  'question_title' => string 'aaaaaa' (length=6)
  'question' => string 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' (length=20)
```

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure it's returning the *last* row...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *append* onto `$arr` via `[]`, not assign its value directly. Otherwise you are overwriting it on each loop iteration.

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $arr[] = array('question_title'=>$question_title,'question'=>$question);
    //-^^^^
}
```